# updating arrays in R

Tags: r

```
#generic bandit class
Bandit <- setClass("Bandit", slots = c(num_options = "numeric",
                                               trials = "numeric",
                                               successes = "numeric"),
                       prototype = list(num_options = 2,
                                        trials = c(0,0),
                                        successes = c(0,0)))

#define a class for bandits with reward distribution parameters for each arm
#following beta distributions
BetaBandit <- setClass("BetaBandit", slots = c(num_options = "numeric", 
                                         prior = "numeric",
                                         trials = "numeric",
                                         successes = "numeric"),
         prototype = list(num_options = 2,
                          prior = c(1.0,1.0),
                          trials = c(0,0),
                          successes = c(0,0)),
         contains="Bandit")



   setGeneric(name="update_result",
           def=function(bandit,arm,success)
             {
                standardGeneric("update_result")
           }
           )

setMethod(f="update_result",
          signature="Bandit",
          def=function(bandit,arm,success)
            {
              bandit@trials[arm] <- bandit@trials[arm]+1
              if(success){
                bandit@successes[arm] <- bandit@successes[arm]+1
              }
          }
          )
```

I'm coding a bandit algorithm that updates my successes and trials after pulling an arm and checking its payoff.

However, this isn't updating my tables properly as seen below. I still don't have any updates in my trials/success tables.

```
> bb <- BetaBandit()
> update_result(bb,1,1)
> bb@successes
[1] 0 0
> bb@trials
[1] 0 0
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

R's S4 classes do not support modification of slots. You need to either use [reference classes](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/methods/html/refClass.html) or a replace method:

```
setGeneric("trials<-", function(bandit, value) { standardGeneric("trials<-") })
setMethod("trials<-", c("Bandit", "ANY"), function(bandit, value) {
  bandit@trials <- value
  bandit
})

tr <- bandit@trials
tr[arm] <- tr[arm] + 1
trials(bandit) <- tr
```

Comment: Why do we have the line "bandit" at the end after bandit@trials <- value? I know it's because otherwise the trials table won't update properly but I can't tell what that line DOES.

Comment: It returns the value; identical to `return(bandit)`. A replace method must return the modified object.